# custom post type and the_post_thumbnail(); on Page

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type

I just started developing in Wordpress and i have a question regarding **custom_post_type**.

I have created a custom_post_type - "Phones".

I use WP_query to fetch all the post types of Phones:

```
$phones = new WP_Query(array('post_type'=>array('phone')));
```

I created a Page for displaying all the phones and i use the $phones variable in a loop:

```
 <?php foreach($all_phones as $phone){ ?>

            <div class="row">

                    <div class="col-lg-6">
                        <h1><?php echo $phone->post_title?></h1>
                        <p><?php echo $phone->post_content ?></p>

                        <span>published: <?php echo $phone->post_date?></span>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-lg-6">
                        <img src="<?php  the_post_thumbnail();?>"> <-- NULL
                    </div>
            </div>
            <?}?>
```

Now the result of `<img src="<?php  the_post_thumbnail();?>">` is NULL and i dont why.

Is it not possible to use `the_post_thumbnail();` on page when you are using custom post types?

In my **functions.php** i use `add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );`

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think i solved id.
You have to get the thumbnail url.

Solved it like this:
  `$post_id   =  get_post_thumbnail_id($phone->ID);
  $image_url = wp_get_attachment_image_url($post_id);`

Comment: There is an answer on stackexchange that might cover your issue: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/232391/unable-to-show-custom-post-type-featured-image

Comment: Thank you! That was more effective :)